# In which Stack Exchange community I can ask a question about Satellite TV setup?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about a Satellite TV setup and I don't know in which Stack Exchange community I can create it? I received a lot of downvotes in my previous questions and I don't want to receive more? Can someone help me with that?

Comment: It will be great if with your downvotes, you saying the reason why so i can learn from my mistakes... Its so unfair!

Comment: You obviously did not put enough research effort into this question. This ain't no discussion :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for this particular site; you would ask on the [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) site for questions regarding all SE communities.

Comment: No, you don't have to ask on Meta.SE. You can ask here if you want. That's why there's no close reason for "belongs on Meta.SE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT a question for [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/).

When we talk about major appliances we mean one of:

- cooker
- fridge
- freezer
- boiler/furnace
- built in air conditioning units
- etc.

Not home electrical goods like TVs, hi-fi etc.

There isn't a Stack Exchange site where this question would be on topic.