# Should site-recommendations be on topic for MSO or be asked on MSE?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, meta, site-recommendation

This question was asked 4 ish years ago [Where should [site-recommendation] questions go?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275809/where-should-site-recommendation-questions-go). With the rapid growth of the network and the launch of new sites, it may be time to rethink this.

The tag [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) is still being [used regularly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) on this site. The fact the tag is still here is most likely a hang over from when the sites split.

There is also a [site-recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag on Meta SE. It makes sense to ask for site recommendations on the meta site that serves the entire network, so users specialising in other sites can write answers.

Should we remove the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag (and possibly migrate the questions to MSE)?

Comment: I think I only once recommended cooking.se here on MSO. In general the questions are not widely off. I expect those narrow scoped questions to be better served here then on MSE.

Comment: @rene well we'd need parameters surely?

Comment: What kind of parameters?

Comment: @rene I think she means that we don't want folks regularly asking whether they should post on Woodworking vs Arts & Crafts here. I think if the question is about something technical, something one could have reasonably thought would be OK on Stack Overflow before reading the specific rules, then asking where it should be instead here isn't a problem.

Comment: @BSMP that is covered in the answer from [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275829/578411). Maybe a bit too implicit for new comers , I give you that.

Comment: There is also [Clean up the site-recomendations meta tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261454/clean-up-the-site-recomendations-meta-tag) from a well-known RO ...

Comment: @rene I'd support that.

Comment: Are you sure this question shouldn't have been asked on MSE? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [Braiam's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370613/578411) is basically the tl;dr version of what I put down here.

For the non-deleted questions these are the stats:

```
# questions accepted closed avg score min score max score no answers 
----------- -------- ------ --------- --------- --------- --------- 
236            110      81     10        -16       383       48
```

And their answers

```
# answers avg score min score max score 
--------- --------- --------- --------- 
303         11        -56       395
```

There are 108 deleted questions.

Almost all questions with that tag (deleted and non deleted) are related to programming in one way or another. I've found [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270406/in-which-stack-exchange-community-i-can-ask-a-question-about-satellite-tv-setup) that I would call an edge case but luckily we have ChrisF who knows his DIY so he could tell it wouldn't fly on Home Improvement.

From the askers of site-recommendation questions 82 don't have an MSE account. They probably never heard of the place and weren't planning to go there anyway. Their user experience when site-recommendations are off-topic will be pretty horrible as they are bound to ask their question on MSO, only to have it closed. Then they create an account on MSE, ask their site-recommendation question there with a chance they get sent back to Stack Overflow as their to be asked question turned out to be on topic. In the era of welcoming this might give some friction.

Most of the users that provide answers to site-recommendation questions have an account on MSE (only 10 don't) so if we are going to redirect those questions to MSE we won't lose much of the answering capability.

While it is true that MSE sees a broader audience from across the network, I'm not convinced that will help much for the type of site-recommendation questions we see here on MSO. I admit I've advised [on topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249763/on-what-stack-should-i-ask-about-fl-studio-usage-and-particular-problems-in-that/249766#249766) I have no clue about, I might not even had an account on said site. So we could see a gardener, cook or lawyer advice users to go ask on Stack Overflow, I would love it if it works but I have doubts.

A few years back we had this MSO post: [Clean up the [site-recomendations] meta tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261454/clean-up-the-site-recomendations-meta-tag) 
I still agree with the clean-up part. I've gone over most of the unanswered and closed questions and there were some rough edges to clean.  A lot of the questions are simple duplicate and those questions didn't need to be asked or answered. That is where my last objection lies with condemning site-recommendations off-topic. We will inevitably send crap to MSE, maybe not with direct migration but by simply telling users: *Ask on MSE*. I'm not sure if someone asked on MSE if they are OK with the stuff we no longer want to handle.

On the other hand: Meta Stack Overflow is one of 5 meta sites that seem to have a site-recommendation tag. Either the rest don't have that many or already decided that redirecting that to MSE is in their best interest.

Site recommendation questions, as [scoped by Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275829/578411)

> Any site-recommendation question that involves code or programming can be asked here.

should be on-topic on MSO because we're best equipped to determine if a question might fit on Stack Overflow in one-way or another and the chances you find a user here that knows one of the other programming related sites is likely higher then it is on MSE.

From a Stack Overflow user point of view they are best served on their own meta. For the MSO regulars there is good base of canonical question available and we're not inundated with those type of questions either. Let's handle them here.

Comment: Nice detailed answer. The most recomendations I came across here are recomendations to either SU or CR, which border close to the scope of SO. If it turns out there is no-one capable of answering the question we could always point to MSE to ask there, but stopping these questions right in their tracks will do more harm then good.

Answer (score 8):

The same as bugs and feature request. Any meta can serve as guidance to their site users as where to ask questions from *that site* point of view. Also it is the path of less resistance.

Comment: But how are we experts to say what is ontopic for another site. Most sites will not accept many migrations

Comment: @YvetteColomb but I personally never suggest migration, just delete and re-post (assuming it is a live question) also to ensure they visit the help before they post anywhere for real.

Comment: @rene my point about the migration is a lot of people flag to have posts migrated and they are more often than not, not migrated.  If you have a look at the questions about migration, it makes me wonder if we're the right people to say what's on topic for another site. MSE has all teh peepz

Comment: @YvetteColomb "Most sites will not accept many" that's not an excuse to not offer guidance. Also, some of the meta regulars here could be regulars on other sites, and their expertise is valuable here.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't think the quality of migration flags increase when site-recommendation questions move to MSE. I didn't even consider that they would be related.

Comment: @rene ah my point is I don't think we're the best equipped to write good answers. that fishing from the entire  network optimises the chances of getting a good answer. anyway it's late and I need to sleep. catch up with comments tomoz

Comment: If we ignore the fact about migrations for the moment - that's distracting from the focus of the question. MSE contains moderators/experienced users from all sites across the network who could help guide where to post and recognise what's on-topic or not for network sites - by posting on MSO - the chance it gets seen by people with that experience/knowledge is dimished.

Comment: @rene I'm thinking along the same lines as BSMP's comment (which expressed it much better) on the question. It'll be interesting to see how many recommendation outcomes are: "nowhere is suitable" though.