# Where do questions about hashing belong?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

If I were to ask a question about hashing, would it belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), [Cryptography SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), or [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: *This* question arguably belongs on meta.stackexchange.com rather than meta.stackoverflow.com....

Comment: In my experience if a question consists of only one sentence, you're not providing enough details. In this case that would be context. Hashing where? Developing a new hashing algorithm? Hashing a value in a particular programming language? Performance question? Theoretical question about an existing algorithm? Recipe for hash browns (i'm sure some people call that hashing...)?

Comment: Other legitimate possibilities for "a question about hashing" are [cooking.se], [sports.se], [outdoors.se]. I'm sure there are more...

Comment: See also the tag wiki: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/site-recommendation/info as it has some guidance what a good recommendation question would look like.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel asking a recommendation question on MSO on a topic that is related and/or close to SO scope is fine here. We generally don't force users to know anything about the SE network beyond their per-site meta. [My answer on that topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370612/should-site-recommendations-be-on-topic-for-mso-or-be-asked-on-mse/370664#370664)

Answer (score 9):

It would depend on what you want to know about hashing.

Use Stack Overflow for questions about how to write the code that uses a particular hashing scheme. Keep in mind that you would normally want to use a library to implement the actual math; it [is your responsibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to look up the documentation for such a library, and it is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to ask us to find that library for you. Also use Stack Overflow for difficult to research questions about practical implementations of hashing - e.g. which algorithm is used in a major project (such as the built-in hash-table data structure of languages that support those).

Use CS.SE for theoretical/algorithmic questions about how hashing works, why it's used, whether it would help with a particular problem, what the big-O complexity of some hashing-involved task is etc. Many of these would also fit on Stack Overflow, but might get better answers on CS.SE.

Use Crypto.SE if you have a question about the security implications of hashing - practical questions about what should be hashed, what kind of salt to use, how to store the hashed data etc. Depending on specifics of the question, you might even consider [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). Keep in mind that hashing has many applications that have *nothing to do with cryptography*.

Use Math.SE if you have a purely mathematical question about the implementation of a hash - something that can be answered without thinking in terms of computer code at all. Note that Math.SE does not have any questions tagged `[hash]` or `[hashing]`, but it does have thousands of questions tagged `[modular-arithmetic]`, and over a thousand tagged `[cryptography]`.